# drop table #temp vs drop myTable if it's not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So far i was using

```
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#tempTable'') IS NOT NULL  -- dropping the temp table
   DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

**Is there a way in which** I could use the same statement for a table which is not a temp one?
Tried like this and it didn't work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(''myOwnDb.dbo.myTable'') IS NOT NULL  -- dropping the table
   DROP TABLE dbo.myTable
```

Comment: How did it not work?  (Apart from the double single quotes which is a syntax error in both statements.)

Comment: yes, i did. Says `Incorrect syntax near 'myOwnDb'` .

Comment: @CM2K That's because of double single quotes. Use single ones: `OBJECT_ID('myOwnDb.dbo.myTable')`

Comment: Yes, you guys are right! I know know what happened. I have this procedure in which i use a `@variable = ' --insert huge query here'` and inside that big query i had to use double '' and i took that part (this drop table query) from there and used it outside of that variable. Oh, sorry for asking such a question. But i really couldn't see this, even if it was so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in MS SQL server should be enclosed in **single** quotes.

So neither `OBJECT_ID(''myOwnDb.dbo.myTable'')` nor `OBJECT_ID("myOwnDb.dbo.myTable")` will work.

But `OBJECT_ID('myOwnDb.dbo.myTable')` will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what other users have suggested wrt `Object_ID` which is fine, you can explore below method to detect if table exist or not using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Your Table Name')
BEGIN
  Drop table <tablename>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work is because you have the extra quotes instead of single quotes.

i.e. You should be doing this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('myOwnDb.dbo.myTable') IS NOT NULL  -- dropping the table
   DROP TABLE dbo.myTable
```

However, note that when you actually drop the table. You aren't even referencing the database. So you can just do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.myTable') IS NOT NULL  -- dropping the table
   DROP TABLE dbo.myTable
```

Unless you are calling this command from another database. Then you will need to include the database name in the DROP TABLE command as well.

Comment: thanks for the info. I accepted Andy's answer because he commented it first at my question. But yours is also great and I upvoted it. (Only that i don't have enough reputation )